# Keep columns hidden after a calculation is performed

Tags: excel, vba, multiple-columns

I am using the code below to hide various columns depending on the selection from a drop-down box located in cell C3, but after a calculation is performed anywhere in the worksheet, ALL columns become UNHIDDEN. How do I fix this?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Columns("D:F").AutoFit

Dim Proj1 As String
Dim Proj2 As String
Dim Proj3 As String
Dim Proj4 As String
Dim Proj5 As String
Dim Proj6 As String
Dim Proj7 As String
Dim Proj8 As String
Dim Proj9 As String
Dim Proj10 As String

Proj1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Projects").Range("A1").Value
Proj2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Projects").Range("A2").Value
Proj3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Projects").Range("A3").Value
Proj4 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Projects").Range("A4").Value
Proj5 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Projects").Range("A5").Value
Proj6 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Projects").Range("A6").Value
Proj7 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Projects").Range("A7").Value
Proj8 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Projects").Range("A8").Value
Proj9 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Projects").Range("A9").Value
Proj10 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Projects").Range("A10").Value

Dim xRG As Range
Dim xHRow As Integer
Set xRG = Range("C3")
If Not Intersect(Target, xRG) Is Nothing Then

If Target.Value = Proj1 Then
Application.Columns("E:F").Hidden = True
Application.Columns("D").Hidden = False

ElseIf Target.Value = Proj2 Then
Range("D:D, F:F").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Application.Columns("E").Hidden = False

End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `Columns("D:F").AutoFit` needs to be inside the `If Not Intersect(Target, xRG) Is Nothing Then` block

Comment: Any suggestions for how to prevent the columns from UNHIDING?

Comment: I did. The autofit is running every time a change is made. Autofit unhides the columns.

Comment: I am very much a newbie *blush*... but how do I put it inside the If Not Intersect statement?

Comment: Okay I figured it out! If AUTOFIT statement is added on the very next line after the IF NOT INTERSECT statement, then it works. Thank you thank you!